# copy oracle sequence to test schema, convert to PL/Sql procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

I have this sql which copies (actually recreates) a sequence from a productive scheme to a test scheme in Oracle, how do i make a procedure from this that i can use as follows ? Suppose all grants are ok and all names are the same in the test scheme.

desired syntax

```
copy_sequence <name_of_sequence> <connectstring_prod_scheme> <connectstring_test_scheme>
```

sql

```
connect test/testpw@db.srv;

declare
 val    number(21);
 s_sql varchar2(200);
begin
 --use the select on the productive db to get the current value
 select prod.seq.nextval into val from dual;
 s_sql := 'drop sequence seq';
 execute immediate s_sql;
 s_sql := 'create sequence seq minvalue 1 maxvalue 999999999999999999999 start with '||val||' increment by 1';
 execute immediate s_sql;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your test/test user has the proper privileges (select any table, create sequence) and the schemas are in the same database:

```
create procedure copy_sequence(seq VARCHAR2, prod_scheme VARCHAR2, test_scheme VARCHAR2)
as
 val    number(21);
 s_sql varchar2(200);
begin
 --either use the select on the productive db to get the current value + 1 
 execute immediate 'select '||prod_scheme||'.'||seq||'.nextval from dual' INTO val;
 --or use the select on ALL_SEQUENCES.LAST_NUMBER to get the current value (from APC's comment)
 execute immediate 'select last_number from all_sequences where sequence_owner = upper('''||prod_scheme||''') and sequence_name = upper('''||seq||''')' INTO val;
 s_sql := 'drop sequence '||test_scheme||'.'||seq;
 execute immediate s_sql;
 s_sql := 'create sequence '||test_scheme||'.'||seq||' minvalue 1 maxvalue 999999999999999999999 start with '||val||' increment by 1';
 execute immediate s_sql;
end;
/
```

But you wouldn't call this with connect strings but with schema names:

```
-- first connect
connect test/testpw@db.srv;
-- then execute procedure
exec copy_sequence( <name_of_sequence>, <prod_scheme>, <test_scheme>);
-- or execute procedure more than once
begin
 copy_sequence( <name_of_sequence1>, <prod_scheme>, <test_scheme>);
 copy_sequence( <name_of_sequence2>, <prod_scheme>, <test_scheme>);
end;
/
```

Comment: Using NEXTVAL to get the PROD sequecne number increments it by one.  This probably doesn't matter that much, but for people who worry about such things there is `ALL_SEQUENCES.LAST_NUMBER`.

Comment: @APC good point, I've included this in my answer as an alternative

Comment: Thanks GWu and APC, so SELECT * FROM ALL_SEQUENCES; or SELECT LAST_NUMBER FROM ALL_SEQUENCES WHERE SEQUENCE_NAME = 'prod_seq';

Comment: i'm still having a problem, i get ORA-01031: insufficient privileges when i create the sequence from the procedure, when i create it manually from the same schema there is no problem, do i have to set special privileges ?

Comment: @peter you'll have to be logged in as User <test_scheme> or the user has to have `drop any sequence` and `create any sequence` privileges **granted directly**. If you inherited these from a role, they are not in effect for execute immedate. Same goes for  `drop sequence` and `create sequence`, ask your DBA to grant them to your user directly.

Comment: tnkx GWu but i AM logged in as testuser and i'm able to create manually, but when i start the procedure it fails

Comment: @peter You need to check your privileges, as I already suggested. You have to have granted `drop sequence` and `create sequence` **directly**, ask your DBA to grant them to your testuser directly (not via roles!) (as user SYS: `grant create sequence to testuser; grant drop sequence to testuser;`). Check with `select * from user_sys_privs;`, they have to be listed there.

Comment: @peter Do you have the necessary grants (directly, not via role) to select from the prod sequence? To check, you can use "set role none" in SQL/Plus and try to manually execute your statement from the same session - this should give you an idea what privileges you are missing.

Comment: @Frank, ehh, do i permanently lose those roles then ? How to put them back ? my DBA is on vacation so i would be stuck otherwise. have tested to execute the procedure in a begin..end block, no problem, is only from the procedure giving problems, executed from Sql*Plus, is there some other security context if executed from a procedure ?

Comment: No, you don't lose the roles. The statement "set role none" only affects the current  session.

Answer (score 4):

You could use DBMS_METADATA to extract the DDL for the sequence:

```
declare
procedure copy_sequence(p_SequenceName in varchar2,
                                          p_SourceSchema in varchar2,
                                          p_TargetSchema in varchar2) is
  doc clob;
  h   number;
  th  number; -- handle
begin
  -- Specify the object type.
  h := DBMS_METADATA.OPEN('SEQUENCE');

  -- Use filters to specify the particular object desired.
  DBMS_METADATA.SET_FILTER(h,
                           'SCHEMA',
                           p_SourceSchema);
  DBMS_METADATA.SET_FILTER(h,
                           'NAME',
                           p_SequenceName);

  -- Request that the schema name be modified.
  th := DBMS_METADATA.ADD_TRANSFORM(h,
                                    'MODIFY');
  DBMS_METADATA.SET_REMAP_PARAM(th,
                                'REMAP_SCHEMA',
                                p_SourceSchema,
                                p_TargetSchema);

  -- Request that the metadata be transformed into creation DDL.
  th := DBMS_METADATA.ADD_TRANSFORM(h,
                                    'DDL');

  -- Fetch the object.
  doc := DBMS_METADATA.FETCH_CLOB(h);

  -- Release resources.
  DBMS_METADATA.CLOSE(h);
  -- debug output
  dbms_output.put_line(doc);
  -- execute it
  execute immediate doc;
end;


begin
  copy_sequence(sequence_name, source_schema, target_schema);
end;
```

If you want to put this into a package, you'll probably need additional grants to make it work.

Comment: isn't some kind of execute of the generated metadata missing here?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the correct grants you can use:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MIGRATE_SEQUENCE(
  in_sequence_name IN ALL_SEQUENCES.SEQUENCE_NAME%TYPE,
  in_current_owner IN ALL_SEQUENCES.SEQUENCE_OWNER%TYPE,
  in_new_owner     IN ALL_SEQUENCES.SEQUENCE_OWNER%TYPE
)
IS
  p_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT 'CREATE SEQUENCE "' || in_new_owner || '"."' || sequence_name || '"'
         || ' MINVALUE ' || min_value
         || ' MAXVALUE ' || max_value
         || ' INCREMENT BY ' || increment_by
         || ' START WITH ' || ( last_number + 1 )
         || ' ' || CASE cycle_flag WHEN 'N' THEN 'NO' END || 'CYCLE'
         || ' ' || CASE order_flag WHEN 'N' THEN 'NO' END || 'ORDER'
         || ' ' || CASE cache_size WHEN 0 THEN 'NOCACHE' ELSE 'CACHE ' || cache_size END
  INTO   p_sql
  FROM   ALL_SEQUENCES
  WHERE  SEQUENCE_NAME  = in_sequence_name
  AND    SEQUENCE_OWNER = in_current_owner;

  -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( p_sql );

  /*
  -- Delete the sequence if it already exists
  DECLARE
    SEQUENCE_NOT_EXIST EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( SEQUENCE_NOT_EXIST, -2289 );
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP SEQUENCE "' ||in_new_owner|| '"."' ||in_sequence_name|| '"';
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN SEQUENCE_NOT_EXIST THEN
      NULL;
  END;
  */

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE p_sql;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      in_current_owner || '.' || in_sequence_name || ' does not exist.'
    );
END;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
```